# progress dialog keeps coming on the fragments

Tags: android

I have used three fragments in which each fragment shows the list of data from the server.Once the data is loaded, data are stored using SQLite. But the progress dialog keeps coming while switching from fragment to fragment even after the data is loaded and stored.I want no progress dialog once the data is loaded but it keeps coming so it may not be a good practice for user experience.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Collecting Data...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();


        getListfromServer();


    }
     public void getListfromServer(){

        if(Util.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())){

        new GetListTask().execute(Util.listingUrl);

        }else{

            if(dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void GetResultEvent(GetEvent event){

        if (event != null){
            models = event.getModelList();

            setUpView(models);

        }else{
            Util.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Showing some code might help to help..

Comment: Are you checking if data is available before showing the dialog?

Comment: when i check the list is null before loading the data, the app does not work i.e. it crashed.So can you suggest me an better idea on how do i check availability of the data?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean, can you show the relevant code?

Comment: the code is:    if(List == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Collecting Data...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            getListfromServer();
        }

Comment: If it causes a crash just post your logcat

Comment: first of all it shows nothing, the list is null and when i swipe down to load data then it crashed and the logcat shows: 10-28 16:14:32.024  29992-29992/solutions.com.rates D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-28 16:14:32.024  29992-29992/solutions.com.rates W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e7d58)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: It only shows those two lines nothing else than that.

Comment: Finally I found the sotution:  First    'public class MyApp extends Application {

    public Boolean isLoaded = false;
    public Boolean getIsLoaded(){

        return isLoaded;
    }

    public void setIsLoaded(Boolean isLoaded){

        this.isLoaded = isLoaded;
    }
}
'  And in your fragment   'Boolean status = ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getIsLoaded();  ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).setIsLoaded(true);'

Comment: Also dont forget to declare in manifest:   '<application
        android:name="MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `GetListTask` extends `AsyncTask`. Add the following in the `onPreExecute()` method:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setMessage("Collecting Data...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
```

and in the `onPostExecute()` method add the following:

```
 if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `ProgressBar` in the onViewCreated() method. You probably always start new fragment to show any of them, which will create new instance of fragment then a `ProgressBar`will appear. Check how do you open the fragments. Also you should **not** create new progress in the beginning, instead of that, check if you have loaded data or not then see if you want loading or not. For example

```
if(loadingData)
{
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
   dialog.setMessage("Collecting Data...");
   dialog.setCancelable(false);
   dialog.show();
}
```

**EDIT**
In the `AsyncTask`, you can use the method `onProgressUpdat()` to report there is still loading, and once your `AsyncTask` is finished, you can hide the Loading. You can also (if you want) create singleToon of the `AsyncTask` and use that instance singleToon to access data from any view without requesting each time.

Comment: can u explain me more on  how to check if the data are loaded!!Each time a new instance of fragment is created so i am bit confused on how to define and use that checking process.

Comment: you can try to make Singletoon task and inside it, set a list which will hold Data, then you can try to check if list is empty or size = 0, then request data, otherwise you can just use the list. It also might help you to make less requests from user

Comment: Finally I found the sotution: First 'public class MyApp extends Application { public Boolean isLoaded = false; public Boolean getIsLoaded(){ return isLoaded; } public void setIsLoaded(Boolean isLoaded){ this.isLoaded = isLoaded; } } ' And in your fragment 'Boolean status = ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getIsLoaded(); ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).setIsLoaded(true);'

Comment: try not to set a boolean like that in the Application class, try to make it more specific in the AsyncTask for example, because this way it is too general for the whole app ( well not the best solution ) but feel free to use it